# How to require specific version of macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode8, macos-sierra

For example: My Xcode project deployment target can be iOS 10.3 — Is there an equivalent to require macOS 10.12.4? (Latest SDK)

• iOS 10.3 is the latest update (can be targeted in Xcode).
• macOS 10.12.4 is the latest update

My goal/hope is to target the latest macOS update in the same way I can target the latest iOS update.

**Verdict: It’s not (yet?) possible in Xcode. :(**

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: No, the desired level of project deployment specificity doesn't appear to be possible on macOS as it is on iOS.

Comment: You updated your question but your claim is wrong. It is configurable the same way for both system - iOS and macOS. You just cannot set this on "patch level" versions.

Answer (score 1):

While building you can define a deployment target. This is a specific API level for the minor versions of the operating system. This will run on all patch level versions for this particular minor version. So there is little point to set deployment targets on patch level.

You can check that you run your applications on certain operating system versions only though with a little code.

`operatingSystemVersion` and `isOperatingSystemAtLeast(_:)`seem to do what you want to achieve:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/processinfo/1414876-isoperatingsystematleast

You can then exit and deny using the application if the desired criteria is not met.

P.S. iOS deployment lets you chose iOS version 10.3 only too. There is no specific option for iOS 10.3.1 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you select such an option when you set your [deployment target](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html)?

The page linked to also states:

> Xcode sets the Minimum System Version key in the app’s information
>   property list to the deployment target you choose. When you publish
>   your app to the store, it uses this property value to indicate which
>   versions your app supports.

So you might change it by adapting the information property list as well I presume..

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's the usual suspect. Works well for major macOS versions (10.11, 10.12, etc.) Specifically, I'm curious about "10.12.4" — 10.12 being the major release and the .4 being the minor release. With iOS, it's straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set a minor release version by editing my project's `project.pbxproj` file, located within your `xcodeproj` bundle.

Once you've located your `project.pbxproj` file, open it and
search for `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`. You can set its value to any valid macOS version (no quotes needed).

The result is correctly displayed within Xcode's UI, and most importantly, is respected when compiling. I've confirmed this by using `#available` directives.